# Integrality of divisors in the canonical bundle formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose $f: X \to Z$ is a fibration with connected fibers between normal projective varieties. Suppose $(X, \Delta)$ is log canonical and $K_X+\Delta\sim_\mathbb{Q} 0/Z$, then there is a canonical bundle formula $K_X+\Delta \sim_\mathbb{Q} f^*(K_Z+B+M)$, where $B$ is the discriminant part and $M$ is the moduli part.

**My question**: suppose there exists $I \in \mathbb N$ such that $I(K_X+\Delta)\sim 0/Z$, then is $I(K_Z+B+M)$ an integral divisor?

Such claim appeared in several places: for example, in the paper "Towards the second main theorem on complements
" (second line in the proof of Corollary 8.17); in the paper "Anti-pluricanonical systems on Fano varieties" (end of the step 4 in Proposition 6.3, but this step is essentially the same as the previous paper).

I don't understand such claim because if $f: X \to Z$ is a fibration with multiple fibers, say $f^*(p) = 2F_p$, where $F_p = {\rm Supp}f^{-1}(p)$, then $\frac 1 2 f^*(p) = F_p$ is integral, but $\frac 1 2 (p)$ is certainly not integral.

Could anyone give me a hint where the problem comes from?

Comment: According to Koll\'ar-Mori 1998, $D\sim _f 0$ iff there is a Cartier divisor $G$ on $Z$ such that $D=f^*G$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the problem comes from the definition: in Koll\'ar-Mori page 5 (item 5), $D \sim_f 0$ means there exists a \emph{Cartier} divisor $G$ on $Z$ and $\phi \in K(X)$ such that $D = f^*G+(\phi)$. As the canonical bundle formula is only up to linear equivalence, we can just choose $M = G-(K_Z+B)$, hence $K_Z+B+M=G$ is Cartier (and integral).